# Database Factory Design

Tags: c#, architecture, factory, instantiation

I am making an app which supports multiple databases. The beerhouse architecture instantiates the correct class from the correct provider using the singleton below.

```
  static private ArticlesProvider _instance = null;
  static public ArticlesProvider Instance
  {
     get
     {
        if (_instance == null)
           _instance = (ArticlesProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(
              Type.GetType(Globals.Settings.Articles.ProviderType));
        return _instance;
     }
  }
```

I have the providertype stored into a custom section in my `web.config` and am trying to create a factory which instantiates the correct DAL class based on the set provider.

The above currently takes the whole namespace stored in the `web.config`, to the relevant DAL class and is a bit limited as it only creates instances of the `ArticlesProvider`. How can I make a generic factory, so I can pass in the providertype *eg SqlServer* and any class *eg ArticleDAL*, which I wish to instantiate?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into using a proper dependency injection framework, personally I like [NInject](http://ninject.org/).  This will give you all the tools you need to break the dependency between your application and the underlying database.

You register mappings with the framework, from interfaces to concrete types.  These mappings could be in web.config, or in some configuration code in your application startup.  The framework will instantiate the classes for you - injecting further dependencies if required.

So you can ask for an instance of IArticleDAL,  and if IArticleDAL requires an instance of IDbConnection to access a DB then NInject will automatically create one and pass it to the constructor of the implementation of IArticleDAL.

Anyway - the documentation explains it much better... but in summary the code you've extracted above is just a primitive starting point for proper dependency injection.

Comment: Hi James, ninject looks interesting, the only thing is i am still learning .Net so wondering whether the learning curve will be a bit steep.

Comment: I have had a closer look into ninject, i get the concept behind DI and think i understand how to use setter injection within my pages/classes. However I am curious as to where i would deploy it, I currently have 3 layers UI, BL, DAL and was thinking in the Business layer. Is this correct?

Comment: geppie - you can use it across all layers.  For example it's common in MVC applications to generate controllers using DI so that you can automatically inject constructor parameters - such as a reference to your BL.  In your repository you can inject references to your DAL.  Think of it as a way to break dependencies within layers - but also between layers.  It probably is a hard idea to grapple with at first - but as you get familiar with it you should see it works at many levels.  Once you start to think about unit testing it becomes invaluable.

Comment: Ok i think i will have a closer look into ninject, and if i cant find enough documentation on it i will perhaps look at spring.net. My app is webforms net 4.0 btw.

Answer (score 1):

> > ...how can i make a generic factory, so I can pass in the providertype eg SqlServer and any class eg ArticleDAL which i wish to instantiate?

I think you're pretty much there - at the moment you're passing in a value which ultimately is set in web.config - and so isn't particularly dynamic.

Rather than passing in the whole value from web.config you could pass in just the class identifier.

> > ...how can i make a generic factory...

I haven't done this before, like you I've always passed in a value from web.config.
The trick is deciding: where the responsibility of deciding which DAL class gets loaded sits.

It can't be in the Business Layer (BL) - because the BL shouldn't know anything about the Data Access Layer (DAL).

I can try answering further but it'd be easier with more information, specifically information that sheds light on the question: where does the responsibility of deciding which DAL class gets loaded sit?

Comment: Hi adrian. The responsibility of which DAL class gets loaded is currently in my DataAccess project, but am debating whether to put it in Common. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AbstractFactory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The [Data Access Object](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) may help? (the link is in java but the concept is still the same)

Answer (score 0):

Just do away with all these 3rd party layers that add slow and buggy code and just use the .net framework built in Provider pattern by implementing `ProviderBase`, i.e. as used by the MembershipProvider. The framework will take care of the rest.

We have to write stored procedures for a few different databases and while it is a major pain to have to write specific DALs per database it does work great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why not use [Microsoft's own solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h508h681.aspx) for this kind of work? `DbProviderFactories` class provides `GetFactory` method which takes the provider name as input.

If you have provider in your `web.config`, then,

```
var conn = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("providerName").CreateConnection();
```

Once you get the connection object, you can get pretty much everything else from it like the DbCommand, DbDataReader etc.